# Issue with Docker container deployment via elastic beanstalk : basex 9.3.1

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, basex

I have this Dockerfile :

```
FROM basex/basexhttp:9.3.1
```

I deploy it on **Elasticbeanstalk** but i get the following error :

> [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @549ms to
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog [main] INFO
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.24.v20191120; built:
>   2019-11-20T21:37:49.771Z; git:
>   363d5f2df3a8a28de40604320230664b9c793c16; jvm 1.8.0_212-b04 [main]
>   WARN org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of
>   context
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@31a5c39e{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/srv/basex/webapp}
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parent for temp dir not configured
>   correctly: writeable=false
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.makeTempDirectory(WebInfConfiguration.java:499)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.resolveTempDirectory(WebInfConfiguration.java:468)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:138)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:488)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:523)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:407)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:100)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:371)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
>           at org.basex.BaseXHTTP.(BaseXHTTP.java:129)
>           at org.basex.BaseXHTTP.main(BaseXHTTP.java:53) [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started
>   ServerConnector@48eff760{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8984} [main]
>   INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @936ms
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

and then container stops.

Now i tried to use the same image and run it via the root user and it starts and works perfectly fine. Following is the command :

```
docker run -d b58e4a50371d
```

Any suggestions/help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a permissions problem: "Parent for temp dir not configured correctly: writeable=false".  I assume the elastic beanstalk user lacks needed permission for the folder but as root you can write to it.

Comment: The error logs are from inside the docker container. While elastic beanstalk user is on the EC2 machine. I am not able to relate the two